# Ticks on color bar are overlapping because the values are very close to each other

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to display the exact values on one axis of the color bar and a basic scale on the other. However, some of the exact values are so close together their names overlap on the color bar. Is there a way for me to make the overlapping names appear as a list or just to the side the other values name? I've already tried rotation of the labels, setting vmin/vmax in the color bar method, and setting the ylim's of the second axis. I'm at a lose at what to try next. It feels like this is something matplotlib would allow but I can't find what method or kwargs that allow this manipulation. Many of the commented out tlines are the attempts I've made with help from many posts on StackOverflow. Thank you!!

*Previous code deleted for clarity*

## UPDATE: Paul H here is a workable example with the same issue I'm trying to fix

```
# Make random data with same issue
x, y = np.linspace(-3, 1.5, 20), np.linspace(0, 0.5, 20)
# two different ranges used to simulate the same issue in my data
fake_phase = np.append(np.random.random_sample(15), np.arange(0.0, .005, 0.001))
fake_labels = np.array(['V439Oph', 'ALVir', 'YZVir', 'XXVir', 'V716Oph', 'BFSer', 'BLHer',
       'RXLib', 'CEHer', 'V465Oph', 'V1180Sgr', 'CSCas', 'DQAnd', 'IXCas',
       'UYEri', 'TWCap', 'AUPeg', 'MZCyg', 'SWTau', 'TXDel'], dtype=object)

# Plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,10))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', ms=17, mew=2, linestyle='none')

# Make the same colorbar 
norm = cm.colors.Normalize(vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, clip=False)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='rainbow'), ax=ax, extend='both', 
                    orientation='vertical', pad=0.005, use_gridspec=True)
cbar.set_ticks(fake_phase)
cbar.set_ticklabels(fake_labels)

cbar.ax.tick_params(which='major', labelsize='large', width=1.5, length=6)
cbar.set_label(label='Phase', size='xx-large', labelpad=40)

cbar.ax.set_aspect('auto')
ax2 = cbar.ax.twinx()
pos = cbar.ax.get_position()
pos.x0 += 0.1
ax2.set_position(pos)

plt.show();
```

The output of this code: [Output of workable example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQDXc.png)

My issue is that the secondary axis on the colorbar (left axis) has values that are so close together their labels overlap. I'm hoping to find a way to space the labels so they are readable. I thought I found a way to accomplish this using axis.set_ticklabels() ([set_ticklabels() documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticklabels.html). In the **kargs section of the doc it references using text properties. In the text properties documentation [text properties doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/text_props.html) the property 'y' says you can set the y-position of the text. However, when I add this keyword to set_ticklabels() I get an error that the keyword is not recognized.. I've tried adding the property 'y' as a keyword and attribute but I get a keyword error or does not have that attribute error...

I'm calling the property wrong but I've never gotten this detailed in editing these parameters. I honestly don't know if this is the best way to solve this, but it's the closest I've gotten so far. I was hoping to use it to offset the labels so they were stacked vertically on top of each other in the same order but far enough apart that the label is readable.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I tried to run your example to test out a solution, but there are a lot of errors in it. can you fix them and make this runnable?

Comment: @PaulH I have updated my post with example to workshop. Thanks for any help you can give!